# Reuse without casting to class from interface

Tags: c#

I want to reuse `Cook` method functionality, but still pass different parameters to execute:

```
public void Cook(BasicRequest request,IBaseInterface base)
{
 // Some code
 // More code
 request.Execute(base);
}    

public class BasicRequest 
{
  public abstract void Execute(IBaseInterface baseInterface)
}

public class RequestA : BasicRequest
{
  public void Execute(IBaseInterface base)
  {
      var derived = (DerivedClassA)base;
      // Do stuff with derived
  }
}

public class RequestB : BasicRequest
{
  public void Execute(IBaseInterface base)
  {
      var derived = (DerivedClassB)base;
      // Do stuff with derived
  }
} 

public interface IDerivedClassA : IBaseInterface {}

public interface IDerivedClassB : IBaseInterface {}
```

I have a design issue here that casting is needed on each of requests execute methods.

How can I make this code cleaner ?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to cast at all here.

Comment: Because there are different parameters in DerivedClassA and DerivedClassB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using generics.

Update the `BaseRequest` to a generic class:

```
public abstract class BasicRequest<T> where T:IBaseInterface
{
    public abstract void Execute(T baseInterface);
}
```

Change your class `Cook` method as follows:

```
    public void Cook<T>(BasicRequest<T> request, T ibase) where T:IBaseInterface
    {
        // Some code
        // More code
        request.Execute(ibase);
    }
```

Change your classes,

```
public class RequestA : BasicRequest<DerivedClassA>
    {
        public override void Execute(DerivedClassA ibase)
        {
            // Do stuff with derived
        }
    }

    public class RequestB : BasicRequest<DerivedClassB>
    {
        public override void Execute(DerivedClassB ibase)
        {
            // Do stuff with derived
        }
    }
```